# Backbone: Navigating to next page after successful response from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Trying to implement Login functionality from the Node server. I am able to send the request from backbone model to node server. Node server calls another site and get the response back from another site.

Now if the login is successful, another page should display with response. But if the login turns unsuccessful, login page should display the error message.

**Model:**

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login',

    defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log('Model: Got the response back');
        return resp;
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log('Model: Login function:'+JSON.stringify(this));
        this.save(
            {}, {
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log('success'+JSON.stringify(resp));
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        console.log('Model: Got the response back:');
    }
});
var loginModel = new LoginModel();
```

**View:**

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
    template:_.template('<div class="form-signin">'+
                        '<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>'+
                        '<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">'+
                        '<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">'+
                        '<button id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Sign in</button>'+
                        '</div>'),
    events: {
        "click #loginBtn":"login"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    },
    login: function() {
      console.log('view signIn');
      this.model.set({
        "email": $('#email').val(),
        "password": $('#password').val()
      });
      this.model.login();
    }
});
var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
loginView.render();
$(".container").append(loginView.el);
```

> > Note: I am new to backbone and read about routes. It was not very clear to me.

Comment: simply handle the response if success, redirect with `window.href` otherwise call a view method to update with the error.
Also you could just invoke the login view, without using `.append` just put everything inside `initialize` function or pass the element with `.setElement`

Comment: Thanks @GeoPhoenix . That is two much information. Can you please break it down little and explain me in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Backbone.Router** provides methods for routing client-side pages

So in your case, your code should look like :

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login',

    defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
    }
}
```

**View**

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.container'
    template:_.template('...'),
    events: {
        "click #loginBtn":"login"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render); 
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log('view signIn');
        this.model.set({
            "email": $('#email').val(),
            "password": $('#password').val()
        });

        console.log('Model: Login function:'+JSON.stringify(this.model));
        this.model.save(
            {}, {
            success: function(resp) {
                console.log('success'+JSON.stringify(resp));
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
        console.log('Model: Got the response back:');
    }
});
```

**Router**

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "": "home",
        "login" : "login"
    },

    home: function() {
        // your home page
    }

    login: function() {
        var loginModel = new LoginModel();
        var loginView = new LoginView({model: loginModel});
        loginModel.fetch();
    }
})

new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Few questions here:
How would view's events be handled? Like in this case view's login function is the setting the model and calling model's save function. `this.model.set({
        "email": $('#email').val(),
        "password": $('#password').val()
      });
      this.model.login();`

Comment: This interaction is related to your view, so it will stay the same, I have updated my answer.

Comment: So view will directly call the model as it is doing right now. 
And router's `login()` will be called if someone hit's the url `http:\\localhost:3000\login` directly. Is it?

Comment: No, it's the view that must call the model.save